# Double click is being triggered when first click is done in an overlay div

Tags: javascript, jquery, double-click

I have an overlay div and a button, below, with a double click event attached. When the overlay is clicked, it is supposed to be hidden. If I double click the overlay, with the mouse over the button, the double click event is triggered in the button. Is this the correct behavior? Am i doing anything wrong? Is there any work around to prevent the triggering on the button?

Code example:

```
var $container = $('#absolute-container');
var $button = $('#button');

// On container click, hide the container
$container.on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
    $container.hide();
});

$button.on('dblclick', function () {
    alert('double click');
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle with an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/o0qsbd43/18/

Thanks

Comment: Interesting issue. This could possibly be considered a browser bug, but I've not read the spec for how click/double click events should be handled when overlapping elements are affected by the initial event.

Comment: Why use the dblclick event at all? Why not just listen for good old fashioned clicks on the button?

Comment: I looked up the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-type-dblclick). It states that  the dblclick event should be dispatched when `...the primary button of a pointing device is clicked twice over an element`, this would appear to be the cause of the behaviour you see, as the pointer is *over* the button for both clicks. *However*, the spec also states: `the event target MUST be the same between mousedown, mouseup, and dblclick` which is *not* the case here, as such I believe this is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

> You'll need to have a very slight delay on firing off the normal `click action`, which you cancel when the `double click event` happens.

ref: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/bind-different-events-to-click-and-double-click/

```js
var $container = $('#absolute-container');
var $button = $('#button');

function doClickAction(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  $container.hide();
}

function doDoubleClickAction(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

var timer = 0;
var delay = 200;
var prevent = false;

$container
  .on("click", function(e) {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      if (!prevent) {
        doClickAction(e);
      }
      prevent = false;
    }, delay);
  })
  .on("dblclick", function(e) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    prevent = true;
    doDoubleClickAction(e);
 });



$button.on('dblclick', function () {
 alert('double click');
});
```

```css
.absolute-container {
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="absolute-container" class="absolute-container" ></div>
<div>
  <button id="button">Double Click Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think on click and double click events event is fired when you release the bouse button. Double click is a single event that calculates time between clicks.
In your case you release button on single click but for firing double click browser is still waiting if there will be second click and release of the button within a second or so depending on OS configuration. 
So in your case second click release occurs on top of the button and double click event is fired.

Solution I could propose is to make a delay when hiding your overlay layer. For example if you will make 1 second timeout and during this timeout make a fadeout effect or something like this, the time interval the browser is waiting for the second click to fire double click even will expire and you can do your double click on the button. Note sure I explained correctly and intuitively.